# PyVISA mac OS X (Mountain Lion) Agilent 33250a

Tags: python, visa

I am having trouble connecting to an Agilent 33250a instrument using a GPIB-USB controller. Does anybody have any ideas how I can get PyVISA to recognise the Agilent?

In order to run PyVISA in terminal, I use the following:

```
export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
python-magic.sh
python
import visa
```

Test: (Agilent 33250a not connected)

```
>>> visa.get_instruments_list()
['ASRL1', 'ASRL2']
```

Have now tried connecting the Agilent using the GPIB-USB controller. 
Installed http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm (62 bit).

Another test in terminal:
input: `sudo system_profiler SPUSBDataType`

output:

```
    H82357 ():

      Product ID: 0x0718
      Vendor ID: 0x0957  (Agilent Technologies, Inc.)
      Version: 0.00
      Serial Number: 8235730073
      Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
      Manufacturer: AGILENT Technologies, Inc.
      Location ID: 0x1d110000 / 7
      Current Available (mA): 500
      Current Required (mA): 500
```

However, when I connect the Agilent 33250a visa.get_instruments_list() does not detect it.
AKA I still get:

```
>>> visa.get_instruments_list()
['ASRL1', 'ASRL2']
```

Is this because I cannot install the IOSuite for Agilent on a mac? Agilent IO Suite only exists as a .exe file. Any ideas?

```
    >>> agilent = visa.instrument("GPIB::1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyVISA-1.4-py2.7.egg/pyvisa/visa.py", line 288, in instrument
    vpp43.parse_resource(resource_manager.session, resource_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyVISA-1.4-py2.7.egg/pyvisa/vpp43.py", line 777, in parse_resource
    byref(interface_board_number))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyVISA-1.4-py2.7.egg/pyvisa/vpp43.py", line 398, in check_status
    raise visa_exceptions.VisaIOError, status
pyvisa.visa_exceptions.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_INTF_NUM_NCONFIG: The interface type is valid but the specified interface number is not configured.
>>>
```

Comment: Which gpib card adapter are you using? The ftdichip link points to virtual com ports I don't see gpib over there. Have you installed the visa libraries (not pyvisa, it's a wrapper).

Comment: The library suite for the Agilent was installed.

Comment: The issue came with addressing the Agilent using the GPIB-USB converter. I needed to tell PyVISA to recognise the different GPIB address for this.

Comment: (As this method worked when I used PyVISA to communicate with the Agilent when connected through the PC's GPIB card)

Comment: So it's a converter not a USB GPIB card? If so, you can't connect with it this way. I assume it emulates a com port? If it is a real gpib port and you have the pci card installed as well, you should specify the board number.